# How can I resolve merge conflicts on one file?

Tags: git, jgit

I want to resolve conflicts using jGit on only one file.
I found this code, but I don't know how to restrict it to one file.

```
ResolveMerger merger = (ResolveMerger) MergeStrategy.THEIRS.newMerger(git.getRepository(), true);
merger.setWorkingTreeIterator(new FileTreeIterator(git.getRepository()));
final ObjectId headId = git.getRepository().resolve("HEAD");
final ObjectId originHeadId = git.getRepository().resolve("origin/" + git.getRepository().getBranch() );
merger.setBase(headId);
if( merger.merge(originHeadId, headId)) {
```